# new Date (device.timestamp).toLocalString() returns invalid date (React typescript)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

The timestamp that I receive is in [unix time format.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCkUB.png)

```
{devices.map((device, index) => {
    return (
        <tr key={index} className="bg-white border-b ">
            <td className="py-4 px-6">
                {getSensorValue(device, category)}
            </td>
            <td>{new Date(device.timestamp).toLocaleString()}</td> //Invalid Date
        </tr>
    );
})}
```

But this returns a Invalid date. What is the cause of this?

Comment: What do you mean by "Invalid Date"? What is your expected output and what is your input?

Comment: *"The timestamp that I receive is in unix time format."* But as a **string**, so the `Date` object tries to treat it as a string (YYYY-MM-DD etc.). Convert to number first, and if the value is in seconds, multiply by 1000 (but I don't think you do, I think that value is already in milliseconds).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Please post code, error messages, markup, data structures, and other textual information **as text**, not just as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: @JoachimSauer - Just FWIW, the string "Invalid Date" is what you get ([regardless of locale](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/numbers-and-dates.html#sec-todatestring)) when you convert a `Date` object to string when the time value in the `Date` object is `NaN`, which it is when `Date` fails to parse a string you give it. Would still be better if the question were clear about that, of course.

Comment: @JoachimSauer the expected output should be something like `23-11-2022 11:33:31` but it returns `Invalid Date`. The timestamp that I receive is as a string.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to pass it as `number`, not as `string`.

```
> new Date("1669198241186");
Invalid Date

> new Date(1669198241186);
2022-11-23T10:10:41.186Z
```